# Ternary operator issue SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm using a ternary operator in my swiftui view to change the foreground color of an item.
When using this as code everything compiles normal:

```
Circle()
     .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
     .foregroundColor(item.amount < 10 ? Color.green : Color.red)
```

When using this, my project does not build, CPU of my Mac starts spiking, fans kicking in etc. Anyone an idea what's wrong ?

```
Circle()
     .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
     .foregroundColor(item.amount < 10 ? Color.green : (item.amount < 100 ? Color.orange : Color.red))
```

Complete code:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var expenses = Expenses()
    @State private var showAddExpense = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach (expenses.items) { item in
                    HStack {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(item.name)
                                .font(.headline)
                            Text(item.type)
                        }
                        Spacer()
                        Text("€\(item.amount)")
                        Circle()
                            .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
                            .foregroundColor(item.amount < 10 ? Color.green : (item.amount < 100 ? Color.orange : Color.red))
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: removeItem)

            }
            .navigationBarTitle("iExpense")
            .navigationBarItems(leading: EditButton(), trailing:
                Button(action: {
                    self.showAddExpense = true
                }
                ) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
            })
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showAddExpense) {
            AddView(expenses: self.expenses)
        }

    }
    func removeItem(at index: IndexSet) {
        expenses.items.remove(atOffsets: index)
    }
}
```

Error showing on the sheet modifier, but this one is correct.

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break body construction for smaller components, like below

```
ForEach (expenses.items) { item in
    self.listRow(for: item)  // << extract !!
}
.onDelete(perform: removeItem)
```

,say, to private row generator function

```
private func listRow(for item: Item) -> some View { // << your item type here
    HStack {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(item.name)
                .font(.headline)
            Text(item.type)
        }
        Spacer()
        Text("€\(item.amount)")
        Circle()
            .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
            .foregroundColor(item.amount < 10 ? Color.green : (item.amount < 100 ? Color.orange : Color.red))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Why does it compile when you brake it up  ?

Comment: @BjornMorrhaye: Swift Type Inference always had it rough edges: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/04/26/swift-long-compile-time/

Comment: i see :) Thanks for the help !!